# gdb doesn't stop at break point startup_32

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb

Debugging linux kernel booting with qemu and gdb. This is the source branch: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish/+/android-goldfish-3.18. The config is i386_ranchu_defconfig. This is the steps I use:

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel ~/aosp/goldfish/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -s -S
gdb ~/aosp/goldfish/vmlinux
(gdb) target remote :1234
0x0000fff0 in ?? ()
(gdb) b startup_32
Breakpoint 1 at 0xc0200000: file arch/x86/kernel/head_32.S, line 96.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
```

However the program doesn't stop at startup_32. Instead, if I change startup_32 to start_kernel then it works.

```
(gdb) b start_kernel
Breakpoint 1 at 0xc0b3672c: file init/main.c, line 498.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, start_kernel () at init/main.c:498
498 {
(gdb)
```

Why doesn't the program stop at startup_32?

Answer (score 2):

startup_32 is part of the bootstrap code and virtual memory hasn't been set up yet, so attempting to break at 0xc0200000 (virtual memory address) would probably lock the system and the kernel won't do that jump.

start_kernel OTOH, happens after virtual memory has been initialized.